# Using "pure" xaml layout, is it possible to tell a container to not resize to it's children?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

I have a XAML control that's very wide. It affects the size of it's parent, thus changing layout I don't want it to change. I don't mind if the control will be clipped, or whatever - but I want the following:

1. I want the control to be the width of it's parent and
2. I don't want it to otherwise affect the width of its parent.

I know I can achieve this by binding Width to ActualWidth of the parent control I am interested in. However, is there some panel or something that will take its size from its parent while ignoring it's children.

Because this is inside a Grid that has star sized columns, just putting it inside a ScrollViewer does not help - the ScrollViewer still grows to fill the grid.

In the following example, I want the button to govern the width of the middle column and the textblock to take, at most, the amount of space the Button does:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="asdsadsad" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="True" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="sdfsdfdsfdfhfkjahslkjfhsafhsakjhflkjsahflkjsahdflkjhsadfsdfkgljdsfkgjfdsjgdshf" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the TextBlock in a Canvas and then clip the canvas to its bounds:

```
    <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ClipToBounds="True">
        <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="True" Opacity="0.5" Text="sdfsdfdsfdfhfkjahslkjfhsafhsakjhflkjsahflkjsahdflkjhsadfsdfkgljdsfkgjfdsjgdshf" />
    </Canvas>
```

if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you've already accepted the other answer, but if you're only referring to text blocks, couldn't you just use TextTrimming?

If that's not the case, a simple Panel subclass would be better than the canvas as you could explicitly ignore the children's size when determining the size you need. You'd still need to measure the children.  You'd just ignore the 'DesiredSize' of them when determining the panel's size in the MeasureOverride.  Then in ArangeOverride, it would respect the maximum size you specified in MeasureOverride.

The advantage of that is there too textboxes or any control for that matter would still properly size and layout as children, but but they would never affect the panel's size.

Here's the MeasureOverride code you'd need.  Then in ArrangeOverride, you just lay the children out as you want, deciding to consider clipping or constraining to the panel as you see fit. (Custom panels are one of my favorite WPF things.)

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
    // You still measure the children.  You just don't use them when determining the size of the panel.
    foreach(FrameworkElement childElement in this.Children)
    {
        if(childElement.Visibility != Visibility.Collapsed)
            childElement.Measure(availableSize);
    }

    return new Size(
        Double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Width)  ? 0 : availableSize.Width,
        Double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Height) ? 0 : availableSize.Height);
}
```